# DynamoDB/Dynamoose error using query with .in() operator

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, dynamoose

I'm creating a chat application and using Dynamoose.js.  I have a `conversations` table and a `messages` table. I want to query on the `messages` table to find all messages belonging to a conversation.  When I make the query, I'm getting the following error:

```
message: 'Invalid operator used in KeyConditionExpression: IN',
code: 'ValidationException',
```

Here's what my schemas and query looks like:

**conversation.model.js**

```
let schema = {
        conversation_id: {
            hashKey: true,
            type: String,
            required: true
        },

        participants: {
            type: Array,
            schema: [String],
            required: true
        },

        lastModified: {
            type: Date,
            required: true,
            default: Date.now
        }
    };
```

**message.model.js**

```
let schema = {
        message_id: {
            hashKey: true,
            type: String,
            required: true,
            index: {
                name: 'conversationIndex',
                global: true,
                rangeKey: 'conversation_id',
                throughput: {'read': 10, 'write': 10}
            }
        },

        conversation_id: {
            rangeKey: true,
            type: String,
            required: true
        },

        from: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },     

        message: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },

        ts: {
            type: Date,
            required: true,
            default: Date.now
        }
```

**query**

```
Message.query('conversation_id').in(userConversations).using('conversationIndex').exec((err, messages) => {
     // userConversations is an array of conversation_id's

     if (err) {
          console.error(err);
     } else {

     }
});
```

Any idea of where I'm going wrong here?  I think it may be related to how I'm creating and using the secondary indexes, but I'm not quite sure.  Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB queries require you to query for where `hashKey = ______`. You can't do a query where you query for a hashKey using `in`.

On top of that, `conversation_id` isn't a hashKey in your index.

---

Kinda hard to tell, but it looks like this is a symptom of DB design that doesn't fit with DynamoDB patterns. I'd suggest looking more into DynamoDB table design, and redesigning your table to better fit within DynamoDB patterns.